# Worker cloud build Error when trying acess bucket cloud GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a cloud function that at build time needs to download two libraries stored in a bucket from the cloud storage

the function runs the build in a cloud build worker that needs access to the bucket to be able to download the libraries.

So, I added the Storage admin permission on the cloud build service account id_project@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

But, I get the error Authorization failed for https://storage.googleapis.com/teste242/br/com/div/model/0.1.3/model-0.1.3.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]

I am actually trying to download the file via public HTTP URL. It is a java 11 function where it was declared in pom.xml the dependencies and the url where it should be downloaded. As shown below:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>br.com.div</groupId>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
<artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.4</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>bucket-central</id>
<name>Bucket Internal Releases</name>
<url>https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this using credentials without leaving the bucket exposed?

Can someone help me?

Comment: The header credential is not added to access an HTTP endpoint. You can do 2 things: either use Artifact Registry to store your Java artifacts; Or use Cloud Run instead of Cloud Functions for having a better control on the build environment.